# Placing buttons in a datables row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have placed buttons in a datatable column, the datatable is the multiple selection type. But when i click on a button it highlights the row instead of firing the modal.

I have a simple table of:

```
<table id="example" class="display dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="example_info" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
    <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 211px;"><b>Name</b></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Cost: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 41px;"><b>Cost</b></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Audience: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 156px;"><b>Audience</b></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 217px;"><b>Date</b></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Venue: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 401px;"><b>Venue</b></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 55px;"></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>     
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="sorting_1">Literacy subject leader meeting</td>
        <td>Free</td>
        <td>Literacy Subject Leader</td>
        <td>2015-06-25 13:00:00 - 15:30:00</td>
        <td>Event Location</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fullDetails">Details</button>
        </td></tr>
</tbody>
```

My JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

                 dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                tableTools: {
        "sRowSelect": "multi",
        "aButtons": [ "select_all", "select_none" ]
    }
            });

            $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            } );

            $('#button').click( function () {
                alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
            } );
        } );
```

I'm unsure on how to exclude the button from the click event defined int he JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tr` click event handler you can check whether the `e.target` is actually a modal button :

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is('[data-toggle="modal"]')){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sze5p04h/)

---

You could also open the modal with jQuery. Remove `data-toggle="modal"` attribute and add `modal-btn` (or any) class to the button.

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if($(e.target).is('.modal-btn')){
        $('#fullDetails').modal('show');
    }else{
        $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/at4fhprm/)

Comment: I'm looking at hte JSFiddle which is working fine, but even when i copy the code into mine it reverts back to selecting the whole row when clicking on the button. Will check over everything again

Comment: Ignore the last comment, i was being dumb. Thanks for the help, all is working. Now to just work out the rest of it :)

Answer (score 1):

You stop the button click 'bubbling' to a row click by using the jQuery stop propagation command:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' );
});
```

Comment: i presume i just put that below the js i already have? i can see what the code is trying to do but i can still click on the button and it selects the whole row

Comment: you need to add the line `event.stopPropagation();` into your existing `#button` click event, also add the `event` parameter. Or just copy my code over the top of your last `$('#button').click( ......... );`